# Compiling data array to pass to Materialize Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, autocomplete, materialize

I am trying to load custom data array into Materialize's autocomplete function. It works when I use the test data from the documentation, but when I use my own array it isn't. I've tried all sorts but can't work this out. I'm sure this is the simplest thing in the world...

Thanks for your help

**I've created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojtramp/qgns7036/)**

**Here's the [Official Documentation](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html)**

---

**Documentation code (working)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });
```

---

**My code (not working!)**

```
entries = [];

// Gather the info from the page
$(".entry_list .entry").each( function() {

    name = $(this).find(".name").text();

    // This is where I think I am going wrong somehow!
    // Have tried {name: name, image: null}, {value: name.., {string: name... etc, nothing is working
    entries.push(name);

});

// This confirms that the array isn't empty
console.log("- Found " + entries.length); 

$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: entries,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
entries = {};

$(".entry_list .entry").each( function() {
      name = $(this).find(".name").text();
      entries[name] = null;
  });
```